# Consumir Web Service com Login e Senha

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-service

Recebi essas orientações para acessar e consumir o método listarProdutos de um WebService: 
*Forma padrão de autenticação dos webservices da aplicação Java para entidades e associados*

*É necessário que o cliente possua um operador cadastrado no sistema, com permissão de acesso "web-service" e senha específica para o meio de acesso; o mecanismo de autenticação utiliza o padrão HTTP basic authentication.*

*Os dados de login (operador e senha) devem ser enviados no header específico
(Authorization), criptografados em Base 64,exemplo:*

*O nome do operador (no exemplo, "wsteste") e a senha (no exemplo, "wsteste333")
devem ser concatenados: wsteste:wsteste333*

*Em seguida, devem ser criptografados em Base 64: d3N0ZXN0ZTp3c3Rlc3RlMzMz*

*As requisições devem ser enviadas contendo o header, utilizando a sequencia
criptografada:*
*Authorization: Basic d3N0ZXN0ZTp3c3Rlc3RlMzMz*

*O login é executado em toda operação do web-service; sendo assim, toda requisição deve possuir o header especificado acima; caso o login não ocorra com sucesso, o serviço retorna "HTTP ERROR: 401";*

Exemplo de requisição contendo o header:

```
Cookie: $Version=0; JSESSIONID=48g39p406ezh_dev01; $Path=/spc
Authorization: Basic d3N0ZXN0ZTp3c3Rlc3RlMzMz
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 1799
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:web="http://webservice.consulta.xxxjava.spcbrasil.org/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 ...
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Recebi o Login e Senha de acesso e tenho algum conhecimento em consumir WebService baseado em alguns artigos:

[ASP. NET 2008 - Criando Web Services II](http://www.macoratti.net/09/08/aspn_wbs.htm) 
[VB. NET - Consumindo Web Services com Windows Forms](http://www.macoratti.net/09/08/ws_cwf1.htm)

O problema é que ao adicionar a referencia ao projeto e aparece a tela solicitando o login e senha e após informar o Login e Senha me retorna as mensagens abaixo e não tenho certeza se estou fazendo do jeito certo, ou então existe algum problema com esse login e senha disponibilizado pelo Cliente?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Este é o WSDL:**

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-hudson-28-. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-hudson-28-. -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.consulta.spcjava.spcbrasil.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.consulta.spcjava.spcbrasil.org/" name="consultaWebService">
<types>...</types>
<message name="listarProdutos"/>
<message name="listarProdutosResponse">
<part name="produtos" element="tns:produtos"/>
</message>
<message name="consultar">...</message>
<message name="consultarResponse">...</message>
<message name="detalharProduto">...</message>
<message name="detalharProdutoResponse">...</message>
<message name="consultaComplementar">...</message>
<message name="consultaComplementarResponse">...</message>
<message name="consultaScore">...</message>
<message name="consultaScoreResponse">...</message>
<portType name="consultaWebService">...</portType>
<binding name="consultaWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:consultaWebService">...</binding>
<service name="consultaWebService">...</service>
</definitions>
```

> Operação "listarProdutos"

Descrição: Retorna os produtos disponíveis para consulta. 
Regras de uso: 
1. Caso não existam produtos disponíveis para o operador, a operação não retorna dado. 
Parâmetros de Entrada: não se aplica

Implementei a sugestão do [Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis) , porém talvez eu continuo fazendo algo errado na implementação, pois ocorre erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ao que me parece não é um web-service SOAP, pesquise por por consumir WS com HTTP Post e esse conteúdo de autenticação, você envia no header da solicitação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que tenha que usar um `HttpWebRequest`:

```
  public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData, string token)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Headers["authorization"] = "basic: "+ token;
        request.Method = "POST";
        //request.Accept = "application/json"; //?
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"; //?
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
```

onde:

token seria o seu login+senha criptografados.

postData o conteúdo enviado na solicitação.

url, o endereço do ws

Tenta colocar a documentação de teste aí, aqui no meu com os dados que consegui ler da imagem ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Rovann Linhalis obrigado por responder ao meu post.

Comment: ocorre esse erro quando faço o post: "O valor especificado possui caracteres de Cabeçalho HTTP inválidos.\r\nNome do parâmetro: name".
Não tenho muita experiencia com webservice, eu fiz uma pesquisa conforme você orientou mas como o assunto é amplo não consegui encontrar uma solução rápida para esse erro e o pior é que no momento eu preciso com uma certa urgência pois o cliente está aguardando um retorno. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Vou editar o post e adicionar mais detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: acredito que era apenas os `:` que não deveriam estar lá, rsrs desculpe. no meu código estava token, alterei como vi na sua imagem e passou despercebido

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo vou fazer uns testes aqui e retorno. Obrigado!!

Comment: O deve retornar nessa linha var response = `(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` ? ocorre erro Additional information: O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (401) Não Autorizado

Comment: irá retornar a resposta do webservice, que depois será passado para responseString onde provavelmente você terá um xml. O que está acontecendo é erro de autorização, possívelmente alguma coisa errada ainda na questão do header.

Comment: Vi o seu print da consulta com o Postman e fiz uma requisição também veja: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]</faultstring>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>`

Comment: certeza que esse usuário / senha estão ok ? estou pesquisando algo aqui mas nao encontrei nada ainda. Eles disponibilizam um wsdl pelo que pesquisei aqui, então acho que é um SOAP sim, mas, pesquisando ainda

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @ Rovann Linhalis!, esse usuário e senha foi enviado pelo comercial do SPC onde a senha deve ser enviada criptografada e segundo o manual deve-se criptografar em base64 e ainda indica esse site (http://ostermiller.org/calc/encode.html) nesse formato: `wsteste:wsteste333` exemplo: `d3N0ZXN0ZTp3c3Rlc3RlMzMz ` com `:` entre o login e a senha e no postman como são 2 campos (Login e senha) é gerada uma outra senha diferente dessa que postei como exemplo, tá complicado rsrs

Comment: Eu fiz assim no postman, adicionei o header manualmente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61682/discussion-between-front-and-rovann-linhalis).

Answer (score 3):

Após alguns ajustes a solução ficou assim:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string url, string login_senha)
        {
            var _url = @"https://treina.ssspc.org.br/ssspc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService";
            var _HttpPost = HttpPost(_url, login_senha);
            return View();
        }

        public static string HttpPost(string url, string login_senha)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + login_senha);
            request.Method = "GET"; 
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return responseString;
        }
```

Créditos a [Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis) .

Comment: que beleza, fico feliz em ter ajudado, parabens

Answer (score 2):

No meu caso funcionou com uma pequena alteração:

public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData, string token)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

```
    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    //request.Headers["authorization"] = "basic: "+ token;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
    request.Method = "POST";
    //request.Accept = "application/json"; //?
    request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"; //?
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

    return responseString;
}
```

Obs:A url deve conter no final a string "?wsdl" (@"https://treina.ssspc.org.br/ssspc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?wsdl").